# How to link Git repository to another repository on a server

Tags: git, github, web-deployment

I'm trying to autodeploy my application from my Github to my Godaddy server whenever I push to my GitHub repository. I was wondering if there is a way to link my Github repository with the one that I set up on Godaddy, so that whenever I commit to my Github, it will automatically update the files on my Godaddy server.

Right now, I am using FTP to transfer the files from my local over For some reason, auto deploy services like FTPloy and DeployHQ are not working for me with the Godaddy server.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Comment: If your Godaddy server has git installed (fairly likely, for a stock Linux VM), and your hosted server can reach github, just clone your repository on the server. Then, after pushing your changes to github, "git pull" on your server. This can likely be scripted with ssh, etc.